# How to Fix "Unable to create restore plan due to break in the LSN chain" When Using the Restore Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-restore

This question is about regaining functionality of the SSMS Restore Database Wizard / GUI assistant. I would appreciate it if there are no responses along the lines of "don't use it - script it instead".

If I try to invoke Restore Database on a few of our databases, the Restore Database Wizard / Dialog reports "Unable to create restore plan due to break in the LSN chain". (As an aside, it does so in SSMS 2016 and SSMS 2012 - SSMS 2014 simply never responds.)

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXxUQ.png)

In each case, this occurred after a database was restored and I suspect a log file backup occurred before a full backup took place.
Since then each of our affected databases have had **many** weekly full backups (we are talking six months worth for one particular case) but the chain is still preventing the wizard from being used.

Some databases are on SQL Server 2008R2 SP3 and others on 2014 SP3.

Now I've analysed msdb.dbo.backupset (I am quite comfortable with how LSN chains work) and each full backup (for any given affected database) has an unbroken chain.

To keep our history in line with our retention policy we perform msdb.dbo.sp_delete_backuphistory on a weekly basis keeping a month's worth of history. This obviously leaves "orphaned" backup sets but must be a red herring as the vast majority of our databases have this and they have no issues.

The time period from when his issue was first detected has long since gone from msdb.dbo.backupset.

Are there any ideas of how SSMS calculates its results for the wizard? Is there another repository of backup / LSN chain information other than msdb.dbo.backupset that I should be checking?

Thanks.

John

Comment: You can hook up SQL Profiler and see what commands and queries it issues to figure out its results; that might help you along. Ultimately, though, you're asking why a particular closed-source GUI app does something interesting when you suspect it is in the wrong for doing that interesting thing, which is probably something better suited for Microsoft support than SO.

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using? I ask because in the release notes for the latest (as of this writing) version has mention of fixing a bug that might cause what you're experiencing. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32897752

Comment: Hi Ben.
I am using SSMS 2012, 2014 and 2016.
From your link, I've just installed SSMS 18 preview 5 and it would appear to have fixed this issue (which would appear to be years old).
At least I've got a workaround until it is officially released.
Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ben if you add your suggestion as an answer, I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to the answer above, it is the issue that is resolved after SQL Server 2012 release. Thus, updating it to the 2014 or higher versions genuinely resolves the issue.